Where is my mistake in solving the limit $\lim_{x \to +\infty}x\left(\sqrt\frac{x+2}{x+4}-1\right)$?

$$\lim_{x \to +\infty}x\left(\sqrt\frac{x+2}{x+4}-1\right) = ?$$

What I did is as follows :
$$\lim_{x \to +\infty}\frac{x(\sqrt\frac{x+2}{x+4}-1)(\sqrt\frac{x+2}{x+4}+1)}{(\sqrt\frac{x+2}{x+4}+1)}=\lim_{x \to +\infty}\frac{x(\frac{x+2}{x+4}-1)}{\sqrt\frac{x+2}{x+4}+1}=\lim_{x \to +\infty}\frac{\frac{-2x}{x+4}}{\sqrt\frac{x+2}{x+4}+1}=\lim_{x \to +\infty}\frac{-2x}{(x+4)(\sqrt{\frac{x+2}{x+4}}+1)}$$
I then used "$ax^{n}+bx^{n-1}+...≈ax^{n}$ if ${x \to +\infty}$"(meaning the $x$ with the greatest power stays). So, we get : $$\lim_{x \to +\infty}\frac{-2x}{(x)(\sqrt{\frac{x}{x}})} = -2$$
There is a problem because the answer should be $-1$ and the problem should be in the last step because in my textbook, it is written that what I got using the last step was wrong. In fact it equals to:
$$\lim_{x \to +\infty}\frac{-2x}{(x)(\sqrt{\frac{x}{x}}+1)}=\lim_{x \to +\infty}\frac{-2x}{2x}=-1$$
But I don't understand why that $1$ in the denominator should stay there, I mean the power of $x$ in it is $0$ while that of the square root is $\frac{1}{2}$. As $\frac{1}{2}$ is greater than $0$, it should be the only one staying, unless I'm missing a point.

For learning purpose you can mail me and I am ready to share my mail Id for learning purpose

When $x\to\infty$ 
$x+2\approx x+4$ 
$\frac{x+2}{x+4}\to1$ 
$\sqrt{\frac{x+2}{x+4}}\to1$ 
$\sqrt{\frac{x+2}{x+4}}+1\to2$
That "1" is not included in the polynomial, it's isolated, see clearly

Put it in another way, $\sqrt{\frac{x+2}{x+4}}+1$ does not behave like $\sqrt{x/x}$ but like $\sqrt{x/x}+1$.

Unlike the other answers, this answer directly addresses the question:

I don't understand why that $1$ in the denominator should stay there, it's power of $x$ is $0$ while the square root's power of $x$ is $\frac{1}{2}$ so as $\frac{1}{2}$ is greater than $0$ it should be the only one staying

The question is saying that the $1$ should be removed because its power of $x$ ($0$) is less than the $\sqrt{x}$’s power of $x$ ($1/2$). The problem is that the question does not actually have a $\sqrt{x}$ anywhere. It has a $\sqrt{x/x}$, which can be rewritten as $\sqrt{x}/\sqrt{x}$; either way, it becomes $1$. That leaves us with two terms that are both $1$ and, in particular, have the same power of $x$, so both terms must stay.

As you have already received answers pointing out your mistake, I will share an alternative solution that utilizes the Taylor expansion of $(1+x)^n, n\in\mathbb R$/the generalized binomial theorem which is quick if there are cube roots, fourth roots, etc. involved in which case rationalization can be tedious.
Let the given limit be $L$. Then,
$$\require{cancel}\begin{align}L&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{x+2}-\sqrt{x+4}}{\frac1x\sqrt{x+4}}\\&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{1+\frac2x}-\sqrt{1+\frac4x}}{\frac1x\sqrt{1+\frac4x}}\\&=\lim_{\frac1x\to0}\frac{\left(\cancel1+\frac1x-\frac1{2x^2}\cdots\right)-\left(\cancel1+\frac2x-\frac2{x^2}\cdots\right)}{\frac1x}\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac1{\sqrt{1+\frac4x}}\\&=\lim_{\frac1x\to0}\frac{\frac{-1}x+\frac3{2x^2}\cdots}{\frac1x}\\&=\boxed{-1}\end{align}$$

In the third line of the equation, in the first bracket, there is a typo (the $x^2$ in the numerator should be in the denominator instead).

@BrianDrake fixed it. Thanks for pointing out.

+1 This answer acknowledges the answers already received, so instead focuses on a different approach, while explaining why that different approach is better than the ones already discussed.

Already you got the answer @Arya369 but let me still explain.
Though I will go by your process only but my step is just very very bit different from yours.
Let the given limit be $L$.
$$L=\lim_{x\to \infty}x\left(\sqrt{\frac{x+2}{x+4}}-1\right)$$
$$\implies L=\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{\sqrt{\frac{x+2}{x+4}}-1}{\frac{1}{x}}$$
$$\implies L=\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{\left(\sqrt{\frac{x+2}{x+4}}-1\right)\left(\sqrt{\frac{x+2}{x+4}}+1\right)}{\frac{1}{x}\left(\sqrt{\frac{x+2}{x+4}}+1\right) }$$
$$\implies L=\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{\frac{x+2}{x+4}-1}{\frac{1}{x}\left(\sqrt{\frac{x+2}{x+4}}+1\right) }$$
$$\implies L=\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{-2}{\frac{x+4}{x}\left(\sqrt{\frac{x+2}{x+4}}+1\right)}$$
Now I will evaluate the limit $\frac{x+4}{x}\left(\sqrt{\frac{x+2}{x+4}}+1\right)$ when $x\to \infty$
Hope you know that
$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{x+4}{x}=1$$
And also $$\lim_{x\to \infty}\sqrt{\frac{x+2}{x+4}}=1$$
To prove that $$\lim_{x\to \infty}\sqrt{\frac{x+2}{x+4}}=1$$ just divide the numerator and the denominator inside the square root by $x$ and then just find the limit.
Finally at $x\to \infty$, the limiting value will become
$$\frac{-2}{1×2}=-1$$
Therefore $$\lim_{x\to \infty}x\left(\sqrt{\frac{x+2}{x+4}}-1\right)=-1$$
